# Using custom id (api_account_id) instead of conventional user_id problem on laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm currently having trouble getting Laravel Passport setup. In my case, I didn't use User as my model; instead, I have ApiAccount. So when laravel passport added the OAuth migrations, I changed all of the mentions of user_id to api_account_id. Now I am having trouble adding a personal access client from running `php artisan passport:install`. The error said that they couldn't find the user_id column. Is there a workaround for this problem?

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in
> 'field list' (SQL: insert into `oauth_clients` (`user_id`, `name`,
> `secret`, `redirect`, `personal_access_client`, `password_client`,
> `revoked`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

**OAuth migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('api_account_id')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('secret', 100);
        $table->text('redirect');
        $table->boolean('personal_access_client');
        $table->boolean('password_client');
        $table->boolean('revoked');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**ApiAccount model**

```
class ApiAccount extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
```

**auth.php**

```
    'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'api_accounts',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Partner::class,
    ],
    'api_accounts' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\ApiAccount::class,
    ],
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go through the code of what actually happens on the [Passport Install command](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/src/Console/InstallCommand.php) and customize it into your own [Artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan) in your project.

Comment: That is not a comprehensive answer